# What does "over its turn" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "over its turn" mean?

> In Washington, the mere threat of another large turnout from the far
>   right, coupled with a large turnout from the far left — among them,
>   hundreds of black-clad, masked and helmeted anti-fascist protesters
>   known as antifa — seemed to indicate that the United States was not
>   **over its turn** toward European-style politics by street protest.

**Source**: [NY Times news article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/12/us/politics/charlottesville-va-protest-unite-the-right.html)

Can you make an easier sentence with using this phrase to make it earsier to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to look at this and think of perhaps a game with turns, and once one person is *over his turn* it's the opponent's turn. But the meaning of *turn* as it is used here is the more usual one of changing from one direction to another.

This has the meaning of *the United States was **not finished with** its move in the direction of European-style politics through the use of street protests.*

The statement is saying first that Europeans are in the habit of making political statements by protesting in the street. It also says that the United States has been moving in that direction as well, implying that the US has had an increase in political street protests over some fairly recent period in time (in other words, has *turned toward* this method of making political statements). It also says that Americans seem not to have completely moved back to whatever form of politics they employed before they turned toward street protests (in other words, they haven't *gotten over their turn toward* street protests).

Answer (score 2):

Ditto BobRodes, but let me add one thing that may be the source of your confusion.

"Over its turn" is not a single idiom here. You're grouping the words wrong. "Not over" is one standard phrase, and "turn toward" is another.

To be "over" something as used here is to be finished with, to not be doing it or not care about it any more. Like, "I am over my drinking problem" means I don't have a drinking problem any more. "Sally is over Bob" means that Sally is not dating Bob any more or doesn't care about Bob any more. Etc. "Not over" means the opposite, the person still is doing it or caring about it.

"Turn toward" means, as Bob Rodes says, movement in a specified direction. Think of a person standing in a street or field who turns around to face in a different direction. When used literally, you might say something like, "I heard a noise to the left, so I TURNED TOWARD it to see what it was." Used metaphorically, like here, it means to consider or begin implementing an idea. Like, "When the bank wouldn't give me a loan, I turned toward relatives." Or, "As sales at home fell, our company turned toward the export market."

Comment: Good examples, Jay.